# Enum not returning value

Tags: c++, enums

AGK_Delete.h

```
class AGK_Delete
{
private:
    enum OBJTYPE { text, button };
    OBJTYPE TypeConversion(const char * type);
};
```

AGK_Delete.cpp

```
AGK_Delete::OBJTYPE AGK_Delete::TypeConversion(const char * type) 
{
    std::cout << type; // it gives the correct type
    if (type == "TEXT") return text;
    if (type == "BUTTON") return button;
}
```

I don't understand why even though I'm passing the correct parameters, I do not get the required return value. As you can see in the second piece of code, I also have a cout command which gives output: TEXT or BUTTON (depending on param). Still it doesn't return the correct value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use C++ strings instead, they *can* be compared with `==`.

Comment: @Biffen very bad advice. Why do you need to allocate memory just for string comparison?

Comment: @c-smile And C strings don't require memory? C++ strings have *a lot* of benefits, and it looks to me like OP could use them.

Comment: @Biffen question is not about strings in general. It is about this particular function with this particular signature.

Comment: @c-smile *Or*, it's about a particular operator. ;) We both made assumptions. I assume OP prefers ease of development, and as I understand it you assume they prefer performance (using the term loosely).

Comment: @Biffen If to follow your logic then an ultimate advice would be: use JavaScript as there `==` compares string content.

Comment: @c-smile If to follow *your* logic then an ultimate advice would be: Use C. Well, can't stand here fighting a stubborn *fellow human being* all day; I've got an exception to catch! Bye forever (I hope).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `AGK_Delete::TypeConversion` to take a `std::string` instead of a `const char *`

passing a `const char *` to a `std::string` parameter will cretae a std::string with the value of the parameter passed.

class types can override methods to allow `==` to do what you thought you were doing, so `std::string`'s `operator==` will compare values.

native pointers interpret `==` to mean in the same place. If you want to compare values in the old C style you are using, take a look at `strcmp`.  To be safe you should actually use `std::strncmp`, and pass the length as 1 more than the max length of the acceptable values.

```
text ---> 0x1234 [ABC]
"ABC" --> 0x2345 [ABC]
```

`0x1234 != 0x2345` but `strcmp(text, "ABC")` compares values

using `std::string` will do the equivalent of `strcmp` instead of pointer equality

Comment: Would you mind to explain what problem it will solve?

Comment: std::string will allocate memory for the string so it will have side effects.
I'd suggest to change you answer and mention the need of additional try/catch.

Comment: and what do you expect the catch to do if there is no memory?

Comment: That's your idea to replace simple strcmp function with the code having side effects. So for the completeness of your answer you should explain why your code may fail and what to do with the failure.

Comment: to be correct, the failure would occur in the caller not the callee, and to be honest pushing C style seems like a bad idea to give new programmers.  Also in C++ it is technically `::strcmp`

Comment: And that's the problem of your solution. You put that land mine on caller side. And In C++ strcmp is defined in std namespace. So it is `std::strcmp` for what it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are comparing addresses of two strings rather than comparing their content.

Use `strcmp(a,b)`

Comment: did you mean strncmp?  Also you do not mention checking for a null ptr.